# Anglesharp get p , h and img tags

Tags: queryselector, anglesharp

I want to take `h` `p` and `img` element from HTML page but I didn't find how can I do this on `anglesharp`.I can take all p tags but I want to take all p h and `img` element respectively.

I can take like this :

```
        var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
        var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
        var document = await context.OpenAsync("any_site");            
        var elements = document.Body.QuerySelectorAll("p");
```

I try this but does not work

```
        var elements = document.Body.QuerySelectorAll("p h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 img");
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a comma to separate different selections:

```cs
var elements = document.Body.QuerySelectorAll("p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, img");
```

Just having a space is the descendants selector, which looks in the pool of children and their children recursively.